# Best way of getting the selected entry from a table view list

Tags: ios, list, uitableview, selection

I have a hierarchy of table views similar to iPhone Settings app. I'd want to do something similar to the done in *General > International > Region* Format: I navigate to a view with a table showing a list of selectable cells, and I want to be able to show the selected entry as a subtitle in blue when navigating back (as the "Region Format" cell does, showing the current selected region).

How should be the best way of getting this selection once navigated back to the parent view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: in your second view's delegate and save your information there. Then in viewWillAppear on your first view controller just pull in that value.

If you are using this for a preference in your app then NSUserDefaults would probably be a good place to store it.